# BootstrapVue in boilerplate Vuejs project

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to set up a boilerplate Vuejs project using their CLI. Using `vue create <project-name>` I selected `vuex`, `babel` and `typescript`. I want to import Bootstrap-Vue as well.

After running `npm install -D boostrap-vue`

```js
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

I have looked into ways of altering their webpack config using a `vue.config.js` file but after looking through the output of `vue inspect`, the webpack config seems ready to go with `css-loader` and `vue-style-loader`. Everything compiles but my output looks like none of the Bootstrap css files are being loaded.

```js
// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>

    <b-modal id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
      <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class AppAuthenticate extends Vue {}
</script>
```

**Image of app:**
[image: Image of app component running]

I feel like I'm missing something simple but after a few hours of fiddling with different `vue.config.js` parameters I can't seem to find what that is.

Comment: try to reinstall bootsrap-vue without flag -D

Comment: Tried it without `--save-dev`, it's on the frontend so I have to do it with at least `--save`. Still no luck, same output as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after looking through an old project.

Simple fix was importing the appropriate css files in my main.ts file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';

import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Easy enough. Surprised I didn't catch it sooner.

Comment: Sadly some plugins/libraries are need to explicitly import its own css. That's good for you. :)